# irreducible representation of a simple Lie group where each element has a fixed point

Tags: lie-groups

I was wondering if it possible that a simple Lie group $G$ could have a continuous irreducible representation on a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$ in which each element of $G$ has a non-zero fixed point in $V$.

Comment: What about the derived group of ${\rm SO}(3,\mathbb{R})?" (in its natural representation).

Comment: What he said, but without the superfluous "the derived group of".